# Django admin list_editable profile

Tags: django, admin, authentication

In Django, I made a UserProfile class and linked it to the User with
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

That works fine, looks like this:

[image]

Where the UserProfile is visible (with only one field).

However, I am also using the **list_editable** option that I discovered today. I can get the User fields editable in list view, like this:
[image]

Very nice feature, but one I can find little information about.

What I want to do is add UserProfile fields to this list in an editable way (the email_verified field in the above example, to begin with).

Is that possible to do (without changing Django code)? If so, how would I do that?

Many thanks,

UPDATE: Seriously, how can I make the question more useful if I can't use links, images, nothing? Information about list_editable is in the Django help, hopefully Google helps.

Comment: Thanks Bala R for adding the images!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use inheritance of User model and get rid from Profile. In my opinion this is better way. Here you can read about this: http://scottbarnham.com/blog/2008/08/21/extending-the-django-user-model-with-inheritance/

And then just add email_verified to list_editable

Comment: I'm personally not too happy with the inheritance approach but it does answer the question, thanks!

Comment: Add "email_verified" to list_display and add method "email_verified" to AdminModel for User witch just return email_verified: Then you can rewrite this method  https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.2.X/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L458 that it return formset witch can save changes for email_verified to profile model. And really email_verified can't be in eidtable_list, because this is not field of User model, so you should hack something else in admin application.

But if you chose first proposition, all what you need  - add "email_verified" to list_dispalay and editable_list